# Formatting duration in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on the bikeshare case study and I have been able to use:

SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE)

to get the duration of a ride but I need to display it in HH:MM format.

How would I do this so that I can then sum the durations and still have them displayed in HH:MM format?

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: I'm inferring that you're using Big Query. If so, the answer is that you can't. Big Query doesn't have an interval datatype. So, you can keep the value as an integer number of minutes, then you can SUM() them, but you'll have to format them as hh:mm yourself (probably in your presentation layer rather than in SQL).  If it's not Big Query, you need to specify which DB you Are using.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am using BigQuery so I understand what you are saying.

Comment: And it looks like I can do it in my presentation layer which would be using Tableau.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: BigQuery is the db

Answer (score -1):

You can format your output using format function

SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'hh:mm:ss') as time

Comment: But, the op wants to format the output of `timestamp_diff()`, which is an integer, not a date.